# Does Scribd pay non premium authors?

Tags: publishing, sales

I wanted to understand the revenue model of Scribd, but their [help page](https://support.scribd.com/hc/en-us/articles/210129306-How-authors-benefit-from-Scribd-s-subscription) is too vague. I understand that they pay authors in the premium library, but if I understood correctly that library contains books taken from the publishers, not those uploaded directly by the authors. How does it work with uploaded books?

I found an answer on Quora, but I could not read the full answer and according to other sources I found it seems that authors of uploaded books are not paid.

The instructions about the upload process just say that if the author want to make the book freely available they have to specify it explicitly and then they say that Scribd rewards the authors. So this may imply that they are paid something, but without saying how and how much.

How does it work?